# Permalink Title link repeating randomly on a custom page with multiple query loop

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

Having Problem with my loop.

I Created a Shortcode for Showing Posts from Specific Category:
heres the loop.no problem with this
pic:1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZwjd.png

Saved Default Frontpage as homepage this template:(still no problem with that
pic:2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztSRZ.png

Here i wanted to display some latest posts on the page after the shortcode content that in step 1:but i stuck with this problem.
pic:3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PweJ.png

the problem:
pic:4 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nyw6.png

you can see that permalink repeated several times and it even repeated in sidebar code.

help me please i really appriciate your time.
sorry about my english is not good.
Anyone can help with this?.
thanks in advance.

I used the code in function.php

Comment: Show your code please, the pics aren't very useful to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: in my frontpage.php   <?php get_header();
/*
Template Name: FrontPage
*/
?>
<?php get_template_part('featured') ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_content(); ?>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php get_template_part('main') ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: Can you add the code to the question, this is only for readability motivations.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/arifurs/61420f59bdc9c00441654c56cbdb546a excuse me pls.here the full code

Comment: anyone find the solution?